# How can I do make_pair within a template class method using unordered_multimap?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following code, I know I am almost reimplementing the container, but I want to do like this, I will have more specific methods and 
I don't want to repeat code for multimaps of different types:

```
template<class TYPE>
class MapTemplate {
public:
    typedef typename std::unordered_multimap <QString, QString>::iterator iterator;

void addElement(const QString& elementName, const TYPE& T) {
    unorderedMultiMap.insert(std::make_pair<QString, TYPE>(elementName, T));
}
std::pair<iterator, iterator> getEqual_range(const QString& elementName) {
    return unorderedMultiMap.equal_range(elementName);
}
int removeElement(const QString& elementName) {
    return unorderedMultiMap.erase(elementName);
}
int getNumberOfElements() const {
    return unorderedMultiMap.size();
}
bool isMapEmpty() const {
    return unorderedMultiMap.isEmpty();
}
iterator isElementInMap(const QString& elementName) const {
    return unorderedMultiMap.find(elementName);
}

private:
    std::unordered_multimap<QString, TYPE> unorderedMultiMap;
};
```

I have two questions related:
If I try `userProgMap.addElement(userName, programName);` being `MapTemplate<QString> userProgMap` and *userName & programName both QString*, I get an error saying **cannot convert argument from QString to _Ty1&&**.

On the other hand, how could I have an iterator like that:

```
typedef typename std::unordered_multimap <QString, TYPE>::iterator iterator;
```

Would it be possible?. That also shows an error, I must use `<QString, QString>`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++11 `make_pair` is defined as below:

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

by `std::make_pair<QString, TYPE>` you specify both `T1` and `T2` to be `QString`, so signature is `make_pair(QString&&, QString&&)` and compiler rejects this, because `elementName` and `T` are Lvalues. Lvalue cannot be bound to Rvalue reference.

To fix this, you should replace

```
std::make_pair<QString, TYPE>(elementName, T)
```

by

```
std::make_pair(elementName, T)
```

then you let forwarding references work here, and T1,T2 will be deduced to be: `const QString&` and the code works fine - Lvalue can be bound to Lvalue references.

Comment: It makes sense what you say but it is not working. I think I am making a mistake somewhere else. The error appears when I call the method, if I don't do it, the template compiles properly. In T_AccessManager.hpp I have `MapTemplate<QString> userProgMap`. In T_AccessManager.cpp I do:              
`bool T_AccessManager::hasFullProgramAccess(const QString& userName, const QString& programName)
{
 userProgMap.addElement(userName, programName); ... }` and the error shows up: _term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments_

Comment: It is hard to verify this without more code, could you post minimal version for example on [goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/) then share it and paste here ?

Comment: It looks it is working in here: https://godbolt.org/z/YrqL2h. However, I am not using the AccessManager class, the current problem might be somewhere else out of the question I posted. Thanks.